# store elements from xml using sax parser to sqlite database on android

Tags: android, saxparser, android-sqlite

I'm parsing an xml file with sax parser on android and store values of elements and attributes in sqlite database composed of 2 tables ( channels, program)

this is xml file :

```
<channel id="C9.telerama.fr">
<display-name>W9</display-name>
<icon src="http://localhost/logo9.gif"/>
</channel>

<programme start="20121102001000 +0100" stop="20121102010000 +0100" showview="5349005" channel="C1.telerama.fr">
<title>New York, section criminelle</title>
<sub-title>Les cartes en main</sub-title>
<desc lang="fr">
Saison : 6 - Episode : 17/22 - Après la condamnation d'un violeur par le tribunal, Jacob, le fils du juge Fenner, est assassiné. Mike Logan mène l'enquête avec Megan Wheeler et soupçonne un homme qu'il avait arrêté et que le juge avait condamné. Les deux inspecteurs trouvent bientôt une nouvelle piste.
</desc>
<credits>
<director>Tom Di Cillo, Tom DiCillo</director>
<actor>Chris Noth (Mike Logan)</actor>
<actor>William Hill (Bobby Grey)</actor>
</credits>
<date>2007</date>
<category lang="fr">série</category>
<category lang="fr">série policière</category>
<icon src="http://guidetv-iphone.telerama.fr/verytv/procedures/images/2012-11-02_1_00:10.jpg"/>
<episode-num system="xmltv_ns">5.16/22.</episode-num>
<video>
<aspect>16:9</aspect>
<quality>HDTV</quality>
</video>
<premiere/>
<subtitles type="teletext">
<language>fr</language>
</subtitles>
<rating system="CSA">
<value>-10</value>
<icon src="http://www.csa.fr/picts/visuels/picto_cat2.gif"/>
</rating>
</programme>
```

but in the second table "program" i can't store all elements (title, desc..)

this is the void characters method:

```
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException{
        if (inCat)
                        {
                            myBdd.insertprogram(id, startp, stopp, new String(ch, start, length), buffer1.toString())

;

                        System.out.println("ALEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTT");
                        System.out.println(buffer1.toString());
                        //myBdd.insertprogram(id, startp, stopp, buffer1.toString(),"");
                        inCat = false;
                    }
```

the startelement method :

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
      throws SAXException
      {

            Log.i("qname", "<"+qName.toString()+">");

            if(qName.equals("tv"))
            {
                Log.i("Dans TV", "tv");
            }

            else if(qName.equals("channel"))
            {

                channelId = attributes.getValue("id");
                    Log.i("id",id);
                    //myBdd.insertchannel(channelId,title);
                    inPersonne = true;  
            }


            else if(qName.equals("display-name"))
            {
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                inNom = true;   
            }

            else if(qName.equals("programme"))
            {
                    id = attributes.getValue("channel");
                    startp = attributes.getValue("start");
                    stopp = attributes.getValue("stop");

                inprog = true;
            }

            else if(qName.equals("category"))
            {
                inCat = true;   
            }

            else if(qName.equals("desc"))
            {
                buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                inDesc = true;
            }
```

so how can i get for example "desc" elements because i get only the 4 first arguments to insert in the database !!! ( channel, start, stop, category) in my database !!